# Subplots on figure not filling Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, subplot, qgridlayout

Im using pyQT and want to plot an image on a GUI I create.

I use:

```
 # a figure instance to plot on
     self.figure = plt.figure()
     self.figure.suptitle('My Test Figure')
     self.figure.set_facecolor('k')


    # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
    # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init__
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

    #I use GridLayout
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

    #Make equal size columns
    layout.setColumnStretch(0,1)
    layout.setColumnStretch(1,1)
    layout.setColumnStretch(2,1)
    layout.setColumnStretch(3,1)
    layout.setColumnStretch(4,1)
    layout.setColumnStretch(5,1)
    layout.setColumnStretch(6,1)

    #Add a toolbar and the canvas widget
    layout.addWidget(self.toolbar,0,0,1,2)  #spans 1 row, 3 columns
    layout.addWidget(self.canvas,1,0,4,4)
```

..in a function I plot an image to the canvas using

```
    ax2=plt.subplot(1,1,1)

    ''' Load Image from File '''        

    M=plt.imread('c:\Image01.tif')
    ax2.hold(False)
    plt.imshow(M,cmap='gray')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
    plt.show()
```

but the image doesn't fill the canvas (coloured black), it only partially fills is even though Im using subplot (1,1,1).

Can anyone help me with being able to fill the canvas area that I have declared in the gridlayout.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI0PM.png)